# Oracle SQL - Count records identical on a subset of columns and display values of other columns for which they differ

Tags: sql, select, group-by, count, unpivot

I am trying to write a query that given a table like the following one

| PROTOCOL | SURVEY | DATE | ENTITY | CREATION_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PROTOCOL01 | SURVEY01 | DATE_01 | ENTITY_01 | DATE_OF_CREATION_A |
| PROTOCOL01 | SURVEY01 | DATE_01 | ENTITY_01 | DATE_OF_CREATION_B |
| PROTOCOL02 | SURVEY02 | DATE_02 | ENTITY_02 | DATE_OF_CREATION_C |
| PROTOCOL02 | SURVEY02 | DATE_02 | ENTITY_02 | DATE_OF_CREATION_D |
| PROTOCOL02 | SURVEY02 | DATE_02 | ENTITY_02 | DATE_OF_CREATION_E |
| PROTOCOL02 | SURVEY02 | DATE_02 | ENTITY_02 | DATE_OF_CREATION_F |
| PROTOCOL03 | SURVEY03 | DATE_03 | ENTITY_03 | DATE_OF_CREATION_G |
| PROTOCOL03 | SURVEY03 | DATE_03 | ENTITY_03 | DATE_OF_CREATION_H |
| PROTOCOL03 | SURVEY03 | DATE_03 | ENTITY_03 | DATE_OF_CREATION_I |

will give me this result:

| PROTOCOL | SURVEY | DATE | ENTITY | COUNTER | CREATION_TIME 1 | CREATION_TIME 2 | CREATION_TIME 3 | CREATION_TIME 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PROTOCOL01 | SURVEY01 | DATE_01 | ENTITY_01 | 2 | DATE_OF_CREATION_A | DATE_OF_CREATION_B |  |  |
| PROTOCOL02 | SURVEY02 | DATE_02 | ENTITY_02 | 4 | DATE_OF_CREATION_C | DATE_OF_CREATION_D | DATE_OF_CREATION_E | DATE_OF_CREATION_F |
| PROTOCOL03 | SURVEY03 | DATE_03 | ENTITY_03 | 3 | DATE_OF_CREATION_G | DATE_OF_CREATION_H | DATE_OF_CREATION_I |  |

That is, a query that will find all records in my table that have the same set of PROTOCOL, SURVEY, DATE and ENTITY values, count them in a COUNTER - only if there's at least 2 of them - and then also display (all in one row) all the different values of the column CREATION_TIME given a set of identical PROTOCOL, SURVEY, DATE and ENTITY values.

This is what I was able to write so far:

```
select protocol, survey, date, entity, count(*) counter from MYTABLE
where protocol is not null
group by protocol, survey, date, entity having count(*) > 1
order by count(*) desc
```

But I do not know how to add to this the list of all the different CREATION_TIMEs.

I have tried to use UNPIVOT but without much success.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Your title says Oracle SQL, but your tag says mysql. Which database are you really using?

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for taking the time to reply: I'm using Oracle SQL but I cannot find the relevant tag. I've removed MySQL from the ones I had included though.